# Type a method decorator to force the method to return the same type as a given property

Tags: typescript, decorator

I want to declare a getter for a property of a class which gets the value of the property as a parameter and has to return the same type as the property. Example:

```js
export default class AnotherExample extends AnotherCommonExample {

    @Attr()
    public name!: string;

    @AttrGetter("name")
    public getName(value: string) {
        return value.toUpperCase(); // <= Everything is fine because it's a string
    }
}
```

If the type of the parameter value would be another than string, the IDE should highlight the method to be wrong typed. The same for the return type

Currently my decorator `AttrGetter` looks like this:

```js
type myType<T, K> = TypedPropertyDescriptor<(value: T[K]) => T[K]>)
export function AttrGetter<T>(attributeName: keyof T) {
    return (target: T, key: string | symbol, descriptor: myType<T typeof attributeName> => {
        // magic here
    };
}
```

But what the type is resolved to is the following:

[decorator without type anotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztbhu.png)

and with type anotation:

[decorator with type anotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s75j.png)

What I want to avoid is:

```js
@AttrGetter<AnotherExample, "name">("name")
```